# Simulating c++ auto when working with Eigen Tensor

Tags: c++, tensor, eigen3

The Eigen-unsupported [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title7) explains why the C++ `auto` keyword does not have the intuitive meaning when working with `Eigen::Tensor` objects. For instance:

```
Tensor<float, 3> t1, t2;
auto t3 = t1 + t2;
```

Here, `t3` represents a tensor *operator*, not a tensor. To get an actual tensor, you need to explicitly declare a tensor type:

```
Tensor<float, 3> t4 = t1 + t2;
```

More generally, given an arbitrary template function, `func()`, which accepts a tensor or tensor operator `x`, and which outputs a tensor operator, we cannot write this to get an evaluated tensor:

```
auto y = func(x);
```

Instead, we must replace `auto` in the above with an explicit tensor type.

**My question is whether it is possible to create a `decltype()`-like construct that will take `y` as input and evaluate to the "natural" type of the tensor that the operator would evaluate to.**

Something like:

```
using Y = eval_decltype(y);  // Y is a tensor type, not a tensor operator type
Y evaluated_y = y;
```

I used the word "natural" here because I recognize that there are in general multiple possible declared types for `y` can work (in the `t3 = t1 + t2` example, we can have `Tensor<float, 3>`, `TensorMap<float, 4>`, or `TensorFixedSize<float, ...>`). It is my belief (or hope) that there should be one type that can be considered the natural type. But I'd be happy to learn why there can be no such thing as the natural type.

The motivation behind this question is that in my application, I am working mainly with `TensorFixedSize` types, whose fixed dimensions are effectively determined by layers of template metaprogramming. Having to explicitly declare the types is unwieldy in this context, so I am hoping for something close to `auto`.

Comment: You can write `decltype(t1) t3 = t1 + t2; `.

Comment: What happens if I call `func(t1+t2)`, and want to get the type from within `func()`?

Comment: You may declare func() like `template <typename T> void func(T&& t) { /*...*/ }` and explicitly invoke `func<decltype(t1)>(t1 + t2)`.

Comment: I have edited the question to make clearer the more general question I am asking.

Comment: Not sure about Tensor since I never used it but normal Eigen matrix operations have an ```eval()``` method. So this should work: ```auto t3 = (t1 + t2).eval();```

Comment: @Homer512 The `eval()` method does not return a Tensor, but rather another Operation.